# Does a refresh on a URL clear the corresponding DNS cache entry?

Tags: http, browser, dns, browser-cache

Say I have a DNS Server configured for a URL with a TTL of 5 minutes. The browser will cache the URL to IP address mapping for 5 minutes.

But, if the user clicks on refresh for that URL, will it's corresponding entry in the browser's cache be cleared? Is the browser going to fetch information at the DNS server again?

The case is the following: I need to set a proper TTL to avoid excessive DNS traffic (so it should not be too low), but in the case of VM failure, the traffic should be redirected to another IP address (so it should not be too high).

If a refresh clears the DNS mapping cache entry, then I might choose a higher value.

Comment: Put a load balancer in front of your VM and use that to switch traffic between different hosts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On clicking the refresh in the browser doesn't query the DNS again, if there is already a cached DNS entry in the browser which is not expired.

If your site relies on DNS failover than in general you shouldn't have anything more than 60 seconds as TTL for your DNS. Please note this is just a suggestion not a full proof way, most of the top 100 websites use this TTL.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP and DNS are on different layers. There is no reason to do a DNS query again if it is in the cache and not expired, when the user requests again some URLs.

DNS, alone, is not a good fail over mechanism. You need to add some kind of load-balancing or master/slave virtual IP handling to have an "immediate" switchover in case of some dead server. Or use IP anycasting. In short, many solutions but even if they can use DNS to their advantage DNS alone can not solve it.

You need to define what amount of time of unavailability is accepted in your setup and based on that it gives you the amount of time/energy/money you can invest on a setup to achieve this fail over.